# How to attach csv file(s) to a newly created PDF in Java using iText 5?

Tags: java, csv, pdf, itext, attachment

After reading through web pages and posts for days, I am still baffled on how to add an “csv” file attachment to a PDF file has been created with “iText 5.3.1” in Java.

In my inherited Java executable, multiple PDF files get created and then concatenated together into one PDF file. 
Now, a “csv” file(s) needs to be attached to this single PDF document. An example, in chapter 16 of the book “iText in Action” (listing 16.6), uses PdfFileSpecification class and the fileEmbedded method to attach an “xml” file.

PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification. fileEmbedded(writer, null, “Kubrick.xml”,
    txt.toByteArray());
writer.addFileAttachment(fs);

I understand the parameters to “fileEmbedded” except the “writer” parameter that the author does not define in the code snippet.

The question, using the “PdfFileSpecification” class how do you declare the “writer” in order to attach a “csv” file to the already created PDF file or is there a better way?

Here is the section of the code that concatenates several PDF files together and now needs to attach the “csv” file(s), I believe as a “document-level” attachment.

Tried using “PdfFileSpecification” class and “fileEmbedded” method. Do not how to define the parameters correctly to attach csv file(s) to newly created PDF. Especially the "writer" parameter.

```
aPDFFiles = (String[])vFileList.toArray(aPDFFiles);

Document document = new Document();

PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(sFinalFile));

document.open();

PdfReader reader;         
int n;

// loop over the documents you want to concatenate
for (int i = 0; i < aPDFFiles.length; i++) {

reader = new PdfReader(aPDFFiles[i]);

// loop over the pages in that document
n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
}           

copy.freeReader(reader);

document.close();       

//  Add a “csv” file(s) as an attachment?

PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, 
    sMainDir +  "TestAttachment.csv", "TestAttachment.csv", null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in this instance to be quite straightforward. I have the "PdfCopy" object of the final "pdf" file (after concatenating several PDF files into one) and the "PdfCopy" class has a "addFileAttachment" method that does just that.

copy.addFileAttachment("TestAttachment.csv", null, sMainDir + 
   "TestAttachment.csv", "TestAttachment.csv");